# jQuery works in HTML page, but not when I place it in an ASPX page

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I cannot get this very simple piece of code to work when placed into an ASPX file.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".hide").click(function(){
    $("p").toggle("slow");
  }); 
});
</script>

In the body:

<p>If you click on the "Hide" button, I will disappear.</p>
<input type="button" value="Hide" class="hide" />
```

I get syntax error in jquery, line 10338 and Object expected on the $(document).ready(function(){ line. Can anybody offer some assistance?

Comment: Can you show the whole aspx page?  Also, is this really an aspx page?  If so, why aren't you using asp.net controls?

Comment: I have been looking at the FireFox console and am getting error: jquery HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized. I think at this point I have a bigger issue than first assumed. It's weird I only get this trying the jquery in an ASPX page and not HTML. I am working with IIS6, so I will continue troubleshooting the issue..

Answer (score 0):

Your **path to jquery file** is incorrect.

If you want you can add it this way:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/js/jquery-whateverversion.js"></script>
```

Or

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
```

Add **~** so that it counts the path from the root folder

Comment: Thank you... that got rid of the first error, but still gets error "Object expected at the line: $(document).ready(function()